# How to pass id @Html.Partial in ASP.NET MVC, or Http session ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I want to pass id our get session id in my `@Html.Partial(view.html)` this is the dashboard page with no model. The index page is other page in same view model when id redirect to the dashboard page the `@html.partial(view.html)` throws a null error.

I want to pass the id from the index view. I try to use viewbag but I fail. I can't get http session id by using viewbag

```
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit 
*@
@{
 
}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
      
           @Html.Partial("~/views/maidprofilemodels/Index.cshtml")
            <p>Something very important here</p>
        

  </div>
</html>
```

I am getting the Session id like this:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("MaidID", cs.MaidID);

return RedirectToAction( "MaidDashboard", "MaidProfileModels", cs.MaidID);
```

My index view live this I want to pass my maid id in this view

```
// GET: MaidProfileModels
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int id)
{
    ViewBag.id = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("MaidID");

    // var id =  HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("MaidID");
    var online_Maid_FinderContext = _context.MaidProfile
                                            .Where(i => i.MaidID.Equals(id))
                                            .Include(m => m.Address)
                                            .Include(m => m.Login);

    return View(await online_Maid_FinderContext.ToListAsync());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.Partial()` would render the View directly with the model you passed to the method directly without get into the controller

In your case,the codes in Index controller won't be execued ,it just render the partial view like `@Html.Partial("uri",null)`,you would get null error as expected

a case related here:[Display partial view from a other controller action, in other view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75738403/display-partial-view-from-a-other-controller-action-in-other-view/75741669#75741669)